# Using $_SESSION to store date and transfer it to another php file

Tags: php, session

I have 2 PHP file and I use session in order to pass a variable(date format) to another PHP file. This is the php files.

main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
session_start();
$showDate = date("Y.m.d");
$_SESSION['storeDate'] = $showDate;
?>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['storeDate'];

session_destroy()
?>
```

When I click on the submit button, the output should be the date (`$_SESSION['storeDate']`) but I got an error instead:

> Notice: Undefined index: storeDate.

How do I correct this so that it will display the the correct output.

Comment: is there any other code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error after refreshing or reloading the page. Because each time you refresh the page. you destroy your session by

```
session_destroy();
```

remove `session_destroy();`

and than refresh or reload it will work. or dont refresh or reload.

because each time when you reload your page. you destroy the value in session.

Answer (score 2):

put PHP code top of the page specially session_start(); mentioned

main.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $showDate = date("Y.m.d");
    $_SESSION['storeDate'] = $showDate;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['storeDate'];

session_destroy()
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your script and except the little structural mistakes you made, all seems working right. Corrected your index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$showDate = date("Y.m.d");
$_SESSION['storeDate'] = $showDate;
echo $_SESSION['storeDate'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```